# Problems installing SSL certificate on nginx with intermediate key

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am trying to install an SSL certificate on my Ubuntu server.
I have purchased the certificate from my CA and have downloaded the certificate itself and an intermediate certificate. As so:

my certificate:            `mydomain.crt`
intermediate certificate:  `GandiStandardSSLCA.pem`

I also have (made using openssl)

my private key (?):        `mydomain.key`
and signing request:       `mydomain.csr`

I have uploaded all these files to my server and followed a guide to combine my certificate with the intermediate:

```
cat mydomain.crt GandiStandardSSLCA.pem > mydomain-bundle.crt
```

I then add the following to my vhost's config:

```
listen   443 ssl;
ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key;
```

But when I go to restart nginx I get this error:

> * Restarting nginx
>   * Stopping nginx 
>   nginx                                                  [ OK ]
>   nginx: [emerg]
>   SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key") failed
>   (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate
>   routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch) nginx:
>   configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Any ideas why and how to solve?

Comment: what "openssl verify -untrusted ca-bundle mydomain-bundle.crt" say?

Comment: what is `ca-bundle`?

Answer (score 23):

Does your key list ok:

```
openssl rsa -in /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key
```

Do the modulus of the key and the cert match:

```
openssl x509  -in mydomain.crt -modulus 

openssl rsa  -in qa.server.key  -modulus
```

These numbers **must** match.

Comment: yes, the key lists ok and the modulae match. I could only list in as root though. Could it be an ownership issue

Comment: assuming `qa.server.key` is my private key

Comment: Note that the order of concatenation of the certificates (SLL cert and Intermediate) is crucial.
@davey answer helped me figure out that I had a wrong aggregated crt.

Comment: Excellent. I was using the wrong file for ssl_certificate. The modulas commands helped me figure out that was the issue. Genius!

Comment: If they don't match? then what...

Comment: If they don't match, then key you have can't be used with that cert. This usually happens when something has been mixed up.